# How to get the version number in a static file in electron?

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I am trying to get the version of my electron app through `electron.app.getVersion()` in a static file.

I have tried using

```js
document.getElementById("releasever").content = "Release:" + require('electron').app.getVersion();
```

to get the version number and set it as the content of a paragraph tag. But it errors out and says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getVersion')`.

NodeIntegration and ContextIsolation is turned on for the window. If someone can explain to me why `getVersion()` isn't working or has a better way of doing this, please tell me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To safely and reliably transfer data between your main process and render process(es) you should use a `preload.js` script.

This `preload.js` script is included within the code of your window creation.

To learn more about `preload` scripts and how IPC works you should read and understand the below Electron links in detail.

- [Process Model](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/process-model)
- [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation)
- [Using Preload Scripts](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload)
- [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc)
- [ipnMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main)
- [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer)

In the minimum reproducible example below I have included use of a `preload.js` script.

> In the example below I have `nodeIntegration` set to `false`. This improves security.

---

`package.json`

The `package.json` file showing the application version number.

```json
{
  "name": "electron-test",
  "productName": "Electron Test",
  "description": "Electron Testing Environment",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^24.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  }
}
```

---

`main.js` (main process)

The `main.js` file which gets the application version number (via the [`app.getVersion()`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetversion) method) and sends it via IPC to the render process (on window creation but just before it is displayed).

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
        // Send the application version to the render
        .then(() => { window.webContents.send('appVersion', electronApp.getVersion()); })
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});
```

---

`preload.js` (main process)

Use of a preload script to transfer data to and from the main process and render process(es) via IPC.

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods
    'ipcRenderer', {
        // From main to render
        getVersion: (listener) => {
            ipcRenderer.on('appVersion', listener);
        }
    }
);
```

And how to use it...

```txt
/**
 *
 * Main --> Render
 * ---------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (listener) => { ipcRenderer.on('channel', listener); }
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName((event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Main --> Render (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Main:    window.webContents.send('channel', data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (listener) => { ipcRenderer.once('channel', listener); }
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName((event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main
 * ---------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { ipcRenderer.send('channel', data) }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.on('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Once)
 * ----------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data); // Data is optional.
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { ipcRenderer.send('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.once('channel', (event, data) => { methodName(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Value) --> Render
 * ----------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', (event, data) => { return someMethod(data); });
 *
 * Render --> Main (Promise) --> Render
 * ------------------------------------
 * Render:  window.ipcRenderer.apiName(data).then((result) => { methodName(result); });
 * Preload: apiName: (data) => { return ipcRenderer.invoke('channel', data); }
 * Main:    electronIpcMain.handle('channel', async (event, data) => {
 *              return await myPromise(data).then((result) => { return result; })
 *          });
 *
 * Main:    function myPromise(data) { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ... }; )};
 *
 */
```

---

`index.html` (render process)

Finally, your `index.html` file will listen for the IPC event and when received, populate the `innerText` of the paragraph element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>App Version:</h1>
        <p id="appVersion"></p>
    </body>

    <script>
        window.ipcRenderer.getVersion((event, data) => {
            document.getElementById('appVersion').innerText = data;
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, best answer to understand how this is working, I managed to adapt this with typescript using export const in preload and adding type on index.d.ts